# Is changing the A record of main domain safe for seo?

Tags: seo, domains, dns, redesign, a-record

I have two hosts with different IPs.
The first one (say host A) serves the old version of website at `site.com`, plus some subdomains and emails (`email@site.com`).
Host B serves the new version of website at `site.net` plus some subdomains.

Both `site.com` and `site.net` have been live for some time, but now, the new version of website is ready and I want to change its domain.

I want to change from this:

```
site.com (host A) - Old version of website
subdomain.site.com (host A)
email@site.com (host A)

site.net (host B) - New version of website
subdomain.site.net (host B)
email@site.net (host B)
```

to this:

```
site.com (host B ) - New version of website
subdomain.site.com (host A)
email@site.com (host A)

site.net (? ) - ?
subdomain.site.net (host B)
email@site.net (host B)
```

I'm thinking of changing A record of `site.com` at host A to point to host B, and keep the subdomains and emails at their own hosts.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is this approach safe? I mean, does changing the A record of `site.com` affect other subdomains or email in unexpected ways? If yes, what's the correct way to swith the domains?
2. What should I do with `site.net` domain? should I point both `site.com` and `site.net` to host B, where the new version of website is? Or point `site.com` to new version and make `site.net` redirect to `site.com`?

Comment: If there is a relation between the domain and a sub-domain, for instance, they share cookies, you should be careful moving away the domain from server A.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this seems incorrect - https can not associate with an IP, only a domaib.

Comment: @davidgo You have a point. It was only an example, but I agree it was a bad one. It should be something they share on the server, like a session.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine.  A few things which may help.

e-Mail uses MX records for routing/delivery.  It only uses A records as an absolute last resort if it can't find any MX records - a legacy thing no one should be relying on.  As long as your MX records are correct, how you route email should not impact on your website availability.

Websites are not (at the protocol level) bound to IP addresses - thus which IP address is associated with which website won't affect this.   Of-course, different IP addresses may imply different systems and/or connections and it is possible that if the performance of the systems are different there might be an SEO impact due to speed/performance.

Of-course, you need to ensure the HTTPS certificates and web config  match domains appropriately or things will break.

Answer (score 0):

> Is change the A record of main domain safe

In most cases, running a website off an A record is not safe. Changing it shouldn't have additional adverse impacts.

> in unexpected ways?

I don't know what you are expecting. I probably expect something different. There will be a transition period (expect the greater of 3 hours or twice the TTL) during which clients will still connect to the old host.

If you are provisioning certificates via HTTP-01 then you need to think about how this will be handled.

> What should I do with site.net domain? should I point both site.com and site.net to host B, where the new version of website is? Or point site.com to new version and make site.net redirect to site.com?

I don't know what you mean by "point to". Unless you have very specific reasons for doing so, then you shouldn't have the same site presented under 2 hostnames (shards your SEO points). If it were me I'd add add canonical haeders everywhere pointing to the domain I was going to keep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For second part, where should I put canonical headers? I'm thinking of redirecting all `site.net/(.*)` to `site.com/$1`, so is canonical headers a server side thing?

Comment: yes, with a scheme

Comment: Why twice the TTL?

Comment: Rule of thumb (but based on measurement).